# Estimating the value of Pi

Tags: julia

I am trying to estimate the value of pi by checking how often a pair of random variables are inside a circle

I will draw many more random numbers (1,000,000 or more) and calculate  pi  as the fraction of points inside the circle times the area of the box.

The area of the box is 2x2=4, and a pair is inside or on the circle if  x^2+y^2≤1 .

To start, how can i plot a circle x^2 + y^2 = 1 ?

Comment: I would change your question to "how to plot a circle in Julia" as that is what you're asking here. And open another question for estimating pie if needed.

Comment: Or, at least, can you please clarify whether you want help with plotting or with estimating pi?

Comment: Hi @DNF, apologies for the title. I am trying to estimate Pi and have the data stored in a  n x 1 column vector of Truths & Falses. How can i extract the "Truths" out using length() ?

Comment: You should avoid creating an array of data. My answer below shows some ways of doing this with zero allocations. If you already have an array of data and need to count the `true`s, you can just do `count(arr)`.

Comment: So, did any of the replies you got answer your question? You seem to have received answers both on the plotting and on the calculation parts. If so, could you mark one as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three examples of how to calculate π using the `rand` method. The first two use generators, while the last one is an ordinary loop. Notice that I avoid creating an array, in order to avoid memory allocations.

```
pisum1(N) = count(true for _ in 1:N if rand()^2 + rand()^2 <= 1) * 4/N

pisum2(N) = count(rand()^2 + rand()^2 <= 1 for _ in 1:N) * 4/N

function pisum3(N)
    s = 0
    for _ in 1:N
        s += (rand()^2 + rand()^2 <= 1)
    end
    return 4s/N
end
```

Let's test how fast they are:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> N = 10^7
10000000

julia> @btime pisum1($N)
  105.221 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.1410964

julia> @btime pisum2($N)
  81.046 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.1416524

julia> @btime pisum3($N)
  34.942 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.141756
```

If you want performance, you should go with the straight loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a circle in 1 line with `Plots.jl`:

```
using Plots
gr()

plot(cos, sin, 0, 2pi, line=4, leg=false, fill=(0,:orange), aspect_ratio=1)
```

This plots `cos` and `sin` components (x and y coordinates) between 0 and 2pi and then fills the area between the curves. Fixing the aspect ratio makes sure that the circle looks like a circle. This is the resulting plot:

[image]

Thanks to DNF for pointing out an easy solution.

Comment: There's no need to split it up. Just do `t = LinRange(0, 2π, 1000); plot(cos.(t), sin.(t))`. (Also, don't `collect` the range like you do with `x`. In general, you should almost never use `collect`.)

Comment: Fair enough. :) It was still early in the morning for this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to plot anything if you just want to estimate pi. Generate a n by 2 matrix with every element a normal. Then you can loop through the rows to see if the sum of the squares are smaller than 1.

Comment: No, don't create a matrix, that is very wasteful and slow. Just run a loop and increment a counter with `rand()^2 + rand()^2 <= 1` at each iteration.